# Is there any specific way to extract SSD name without "/"?

Tags: bash

In my current system, I have 3 SSDs, sda, sdb and sdc. The OS is installed in sdc.
I am trying to extract the **SSDs without the OS** installed in it. So, this command

```
echo $(eval $(lsblk -oMOUNTPOINT,PKNAME -P | grep 'MOUNTPOINT="/"'); echo $PKNAME | sed 's/[0-9]*$//')
```

returns sdc.
But if I want the drive without OS, how should I modify the above command?

grep 'MOUNTPOINT!="/"' doesn't return anything.

The bash script provided by Renaud works as expected on systems with raw drives. In case, if the system has LVM partitions then it returns only dm-1.
How to handle this case? To get the correct SSD name on either raw or LVM systems?
On the LVM system, lsblk returns. The expected output is sdb

```
 NAME                MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
    sda                  8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
    ├─sda1               8:1    0  512M  0 part /boot/efi
    ├─sda2               8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
    └─sda3               8:3    0  1.8T  0 part
    ├─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv-real
    │                         253:1    0  880G  0 lvm
    │ ├─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:2    0  880G  0 lvm  /
    │ └─ubuntu--vg-clean      253:4    0  880G  0 lvm
    └─ubuntu--vg-clean-cow    253:3    0  400G  0 lvm
      └─ubuntu--vg-clean      253:4    0  880G  0 lvm
    sdb                           8:16   0  1.8T  0 disk
```

On the raw drive, lsblk returns

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0     2G  0 part
└─sdb2   8:18   0 463.8G  0 part
sdc      8:32   0 232.9G  0 disk
├─sdc1   8:33   0   156M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdc2   8:34   0  26.7G  0 part /boot
├─sdc3   8:35   0 182.7G  0 part /
└─sdc4   8:36   0  23.4G  0 part [SWAP]
```

Here the expected output is sda or sdc.

Comment: `lsblk -oMOUNTPOINT,PKNAME -P | grep -Po '(?<=MOUNTPOINT="/" PKNAME=").*(?=")'`

Comment: `lsblk -oMOUNTPOINT,PKNAME -P | awk -F'"' '/MOUNTPOINT="\/"/{print $(NF-1)}'`

Comment: @Jetchisel, both your commands are printing sdc which is the drive with OS. but I am looking for the drive without OS. I am trying to find out based on the absence of "/" in the drive.

Comment: Looking at the [revision history](/posts/70066002/revisions), this question has totally changed since you asked it, so all the comments and answers don't make sense. It's also not about [tag:bash]. You'd be better off asking a new question. And for posterity, I'd recommend rolling back to an old revision.

Comment: `sdb` is missing from the output

Comment: @wjandrea, as suggested, I am rolling back to the original version. Now closing this question as well. Apologies for any inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` has a `-v` option to print only non-matching lines. So:

```
lsblk -oMOUNTPOINT,PKNAME -P | grep -v 'MOUNTPOINT="/"'
```

should exclude this drive. But note that if you have more than one other drive the rest of your script will not work as you would like. Only the last drive will be considered because it overrides the others. A loop would probably be closer to your needs:

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do
  eval "$line"
  sed 's/[0-9]*$//' <<< "$PKNAME"
done < <(lsblk -oMOUNTPOINT,PKNAME -P | grep -v 'MOUNTPOINT="/"')
```

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't work on systems with LVM. It shows the output as dm-1.  Is it possible to change this to consider both LVM and raw drives?

Comment: @hago Then you probably need to use another `lsblk` option than `PKNAME` (`NAME`, maybe?). Please edit your question, show the `lsblk` options you want to use, an example of the `lsblk` output with these options and the corresponding desired output after filtering.

Comment: I have edited the question with the details now.

Comment: @hago You do not show the full `lsblk` output. In the first you show there is no `sdb` at all. So, where is the `sdb` output you expect supposed to come from? Same for the second `lsblk` output you show. It contains none of the `sda` or `sdb` you expect. Please try to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: sorry I was totally in the wrong way of solving the issue. So, I have re-framed my question.

Comment: I ended up modifying the above command to 
echo $(eval $(lsblk -oMOUNTPOINT,NAME -P | grep -v 'MOUNTPOINT="/"'); echo $NAME)
Now, I got my problem solved.